# Dynamically changing md-selection attribute in Vue material table destroys table layout

Tags: material-design, vuejs2

The table row looks like this:

```
 <md-table-row v-bind:class="{'md-selected': isActive(rowIndex)}" 
    md-selection v-for="(row, rowIndex) in recordings" 
    :key="rowIndex"   
    :md-item="row" >
```

I would like to remove the md-selection attribute from the row, if a certain condition is true. I know how to make this work but it destroys the layout of the table.